# Anular Evento Click JQuery preventDefault

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

Olá, não estou conseguindo utilizar o addClass quando dou um response em minha página utilizando ajax. O que ocorre é que ele adiciona a class no meu elemento html por um momento, mas o comportamento é como se a página estivesse sendo carregada, sendo assim nada acontece.
Estou realizando uma paginação.

```js
$('.waves-effect a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).data('href');

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    success: function(response) {
      $('#form').html(response)
    },

    complete: function() {
      $(".waves-effect").click(function() {
        $(this).addClass("active");
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
  <li class="waves-effect"><a data-href="webmail.php?page=<?=$i?>"><?=$i?></a></li>
```

Sou meio leigo em JQuery, agradeço o help de todos.

Comment: Testei aqui e está ok. Já tentou remover esse evento `$(".waves-effect").click(function() {}` ? Deixar apenas o `$(this).addClass("active");` no `complete`?

Comment: Eu preciso acrescentar a class "active", somente onde no elemento clicado (this). Tentei remover e não funfou =/

Comment: Tenta fazer como o Fernando postou abaixo. O `complete` só vai adicionar a class `activity` quando a requisição for completada.

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```
<!-- NO HTML adicione o href="#" -->
<li class="waves-effect"><a href="#" data-href="webmail.php?page=<?=$i?>"><?=$i?></a></li>

<!-- NO JAVASCRIPT -->
$('.waves-effect a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var element = $(this)
  var url = element.data('href');

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    success: function(response) {
      $('#form').html(response)
    },

    complete: function() {
      $('.waves-effect a').removeClass('active')
      element.addClass("active");
    }
  });
});
```

Teste você mesmo: https://jsfiddle.net/hbq0h831/1/

Comment: dessa forma, ele está adicionando o active antes da requisição ser completada, logo após o active é eliminado

Comment: Certo, então vc não precisa do evento de click dentro do complete, pode tentar algo assim:

    `complete: function() {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }`

Comment: Foi o que nosso amigo Valdeir sugeriu nas respostas acima, porém não funciona pro 'this', só funciona quando eu implemento a classe no lugar do 'this', mas aí ele faz o addClass pra todos =/

Comment: Não tinha reparado... Então troque o `$(this)` por `$('.waves-effect')`

Comment: Acho que enfim, entendi o problema, vou rescrever e editar a resposta..

Comment: Dá uma olhada..

Comment: Fernando, fiz as modificações e ainda não obtive efeito.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71232/discussion-between-fernando-m-tenorio-and-gemerich).

Comment: Aqui não funciona de maneira nenhuma, não sei se é porque estou usando Materialize..

Comment: Consegue criar algo no jsfiddle para analisarmos melhor o cenário??